# Question involving vectors and lines

Tags: vectors

Determine the reduced equations of the line r that passes trough $A(2,-1,4)$ and $B=r_1\cap r_2$, where $r_1:\frac{x-1}{2}=\frac{y-3}{4}=\frac{z-1}{-2}$ and $r_2:\frac{x}{3}=\frac{y-1}{2}=z-2$

My english is bad, I don't know if reduced form is the correct word. But, if we have$x=x_0+at, y=y_0+bt, z=z_0+ct$, we put $x$ in function of $t$ and substitute in $y$ and $z$. That's what I mean by "reduced equations".

The answer given by the textbook is $y=-x+1,z=x+2$. Which is not what I been getting.

What I did until this time peharps my be better understand with a photo.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your 4th step, you copied the wrong number. You went from $y=3+4t$ and $y=1+2h$ to $3+4t=2h$.

Same kind of mistakes happened later too. Be careful to copy the numbers correctly.